# Is there a way to make the jQuery UI slider start with 0 on top instead of on bottom?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, uislider

Look at this [demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#slider-vertical) of the jQuery UI Slider.

Notice how when the handle is down the bottom, the value is 0?

Is there a way to reverse this, so the handle up the very top is 0, and the handle down the bottom is the max range?

I've played a bit with the options, but so far have been unable to get it to work.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Don't reverse it, take the easy way out :) Just subtract the value from your max, for example:

```
$("#slider-vertical").slider({
    orientation: "vertical",
    range: "min",
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        $("#amount").val(100 - ui.value);
    }
});
```

This just goes `max-value`, effectively reversing it, [you can see a quick demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/GNaRY/1/).

Comment: The trouble with this is that the 'fill in' is still growing from bottom to top. I also want a top-to-bottom version of this, with the fill-in working that way too. Time to start hacking...

Comment: @IainMNorman doesn't work for me.  absolute value answer is most workable for me.

Comment: Issue with this approach is if you want to include other buttons which jump/set a specific value. `slide` is never triggered but `change` is, however then modifying the value in `change` is somewhat circular. The position of the slider vs the numeric value gets out of sync.

Answer (score 16):

Probably, usage of negative values will be more elegant:

```
$('#slider').slider({
    min: -100,
    max: 0,
    value: -50,
    step: 1
});
```

Just use absolute value, instead of an actual one, where you need it.

Comment: until they have a new option for this issue, this is the correct answer.  i wish i could +2 considering the cleverness

Comment: Much less hacky than the accepted answer. Thank you.

Comment: if you start below zero and therefore need negative values, use value * -1 rather than math.abs

Answer (score 3):

```
$(function() {
    $("#slider-vertical").slider({
      orientation: "vertical",
      range: "max", // <--- needed...
      min: 0,
      max: 100,
      value: 60,
      slide: function(event, ui) {
        $("#amount").val(100 - ui.value); // basic math operation..
      }
    });
  });
```

[demo...](http://jsbin.com/ojeva4/edit)
​

Answer (score -1):

You could just turn it upside down using css3.

```
#slider {
     -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
     -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
     -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
     -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
     transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid that has the crazy side-effect of mouse input being reversed.

Comment: You are right, so that is not an option. It's funny though ;-)

Comment: The funniest answer!! LOL