# Is it possible to have input type="range" values listed in descending order using jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, forms, mobile, slider, range

I am trying to have a form where the values are weighted differently depending on if you slide right or slide left. By default input type="range" is listed in ascending order? Do you know a way to make a class to have one go descending?

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jacoblett/dzah8qv1/

```
<label for="slider-step">Ascending:<br/>
    0, 2, 4, <b>5</b>, 6, 8, 10
</label>
<input type="range" name="slider-step" id="slider-step" value="5" min="0" max="10" step="2" />

<label for="slider-step">How to get descending? <br/>
    10, 8, 6, <b>5</b>, 4, 2, 0
</label>
<input type="range" name="slider-step" id="slider-step" value="5" min="0" max="10" step="2" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I don't think there is a way with `input range`, but if you use a control such as [jQuery UI slider](http://jqueryui.com/slider/) you could do it. [See this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3083874/is-there-a-way-to-make-the-jquery-ui-slider-start-with-0-on-top-instead-of-on-bo)

Comment: Hi Diego thank you for your help. I forked that solution and it works. Now the challenge is trying to theme it to match the jquery mobile controls. http://jsfiddle.net/jacoblett/vowyetg2/

Comment: I achieved to do it without using jQuery UI! Check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here there is a solution without using jQuery UI.

```
$(function() {
    var max = parseInt($("#slider-step2").attr("max"));
    $("#slider-step2").bind("change", function() {
        $("#slider-step2").val(max - parseInt($("#slider-step2").val()));
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/paska/dzah8qv1/1/

**Update**: To be able to reuse it you can:

```
// For all .descendingSlider:
$(function() {
    $(".descendingSlider").bind("change", function() {
        var max = parseInt($(this).attr("max"));
        $(this).val(max - parseInt($(this).val()));
    });
});
```

**Or a cleaner way:**

```
// A function and an "automatic creation" for the .descendingSlider:
$.fn.descendingSlider = function() {
    $(this).data("max", parseInt($(this).attr("max")));
    $(this).bind("change", function() {
        var max = $(this).data("max");
        $(this).val(max - parseInt($(this).val()));
    });
};

$(function() {
    $(".descendingSlider").descendingSlider();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/paska/dzah8qv1/2/

Comment: Hi Diego. Thats awesome. Is it possible to have that as a function so that it can target sliders with a CSS class of .descendingSlider so that it can be reused?

Comment: Thank you! I tried creating a demo page outside of js fiddle and it doesn't seem to work now. Do you have an idea why that would happen> https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/144838671/iiq-survey/ui-mobile-fiddle.html

Comment: I've just updated. It was just the order of the code. Also added a fiddle.

Comment: Hi Diego. I figured out why it was not working outside of jsfiddle. The script you wrote needs to be added to the document head and not the body. Not sure why that is. Thank you very much for your help with this.

Comment: It probably depends on where you add the scripts references. It should be able to add it to the `body`.